# How to convert time to " time ago " in android

Tags: android, datetime, time, calendar

My server. It return time :

```
"2016-01-24T16:00:00.000Z"
```

I want

1 : convert to String.

2 : I want it show " time ago " when load it from server.

Please. Help me!

Comment: buddy, you've to show the code that you tried , otherwise hardly you get help here

Comment: I haven't idea for this work :(

Comment: @anhthangBui have you solved this?

Answer (score 50):

I see mainly three ways:

a) built-in options using `SimpleDateFormat` and [DateUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString(long,%20long,%20long))

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
  sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
  try {
         long time = sdf.parse("2016-01-24T16:00:00.000Z").getTime();
         long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
         CharSequence ago =
                    DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(time, now, DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

b) external library [ocpsoft/PrettyTime](https://github.com/ocpsoft/prettytime) (based on `java.util.Date`)

Here you have to use `SimpleDateFormat`, too, to produce the `time`-result as interpretation of "2016-01-24T16:00:00.000Z".

import below lib in your app

`implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.1.Final'`

```
PrettyTime prettyTime = new PrettyTime(Locale.getDefault());
String ago = prettyTime.format(new Date(time));
```

c) using my library [Time4A](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4A) (heavyweight but with best i18n-support)

```
Moment moment = Iso8601Format.EXTENDED_DATE_TIME_OFFSET.parse("2016-01-24T16:00:00.000Z");
String ago = PrettyTime.of(Locale.getDefault()).printRelativeInStdTimezone(moment);
```

Comment: Unhandled execption java.text.ParseExecption on line `long time = sdf.parse("2016-01-24T16:00:00.000Z").getTime();` What's wrong?

Comment: @MichaelJulyusChristopherM. The method `parse(...)` is declared to throw a checked exception, therefore your test method calling `parse(...)` has to declare it, too (or to catch it and handle but not ignore it in a sensible way, for example logging).

Comment: getRelativeTimeSpanString only works for date differences that are less than a week. The documentation does not state this, but you will discover this nasty issue when you go to use the API. This is documented elsewhere in Stackoverflow.

Comment: @AndroidDev The doc of `getRelativeTimeSpanString()` does state the week limitation for the `minResolution`-parameter: "Pass one of 0, MINUTE_IN_MILLIS, HOUR_IN_MILLIS, DAY_IN_MILLIS, WEEK_IN_MILLIS" So it is not a limitation of my answer but of `DateUtil`-API. And the OP has not even formulated a request for overcoming this limitation. So I think my answer is still valid, and furthermore, presents a first-class alternative with Time4A which can also present differences in months or years.

Answer (score 32):

1 -  create date formatter:

```
public static final SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
```

2 - create Date object

```
String dateStr = "2016-01-24T16:00:00.000Z";
Date date = inputFormat.parse(dateStr);
```

3 - Use Android DateUtils to create a nice Display string:

```
String niceDateStr = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(date.getTime() , Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
```

Comment: This is the best way, imo. There's no need to roll your own and check for days, hours, and minutes when Android has build in method for this

Comment: it does not actually create an "ago" string though.

Comment: I am wondering. This answer has been posted almost 9 months after mine but does not add anything new (looks almost like a copy of part a in my answer) and even contains a serious mistake (the line in my answer setting the timezone offset on the formatter is missing!).

Comment: Speculating @MenoHochschild but it's probably because the default sorting for answers on Stack Overflow is now "Active" and not "Votes" so yours is bubbling down.

Comment: thanks, how to translate the niceDateStr?

Comment: it shows upto 7 days? what about to two months like 56 months ago

Comment: This solution is really bad. Please stop upvoting it. It only works for 7 days. This is well published throughout SO. Why the hell Google includes this crap API is beyond me.

Answer (score 26):

using @Excelso_Widi code, i was able to overcome,

I modified his code and also translated to English.

```
public class TimeAgo2 {

    public String covertTimeToText(String dataDate) {

        String convTime = null;

        String prefix = "";
        String suffix = "Ago";

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
            Date pasTime = dateFormat.parse(dataDate);

            Date nowTime = new Date();

            long dateDiff = nowTime.getTime() - pasTime.getTime();

            long second = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(dateDiff);
            long minute = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(dateDiff);
            long hour   = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(dateDiff);
            long day  = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(dateDiff);

            if (second < 60) {
                convTime = second + " Seconds " + suffix;
            } else if (minute < 60) {
                convTime = minute + " Minutes "+suffix;
            } else if (hour < 24) {
                convTime = hour + " Hours "+suffix;
            } else if (day >= 7) {
                if (day > 360) {
                    convTime = (day / 360) + " Years " + suffix;
                } else if (day > 30) {
                    convTime = (day / 30) + " Months " + suffix;
                } else {
                    convTime = (day / 7) + " Week " + suffix;
                }
            } else if (day < 7) {
                convTime = day+" Days "+suffix;
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("ConvTimeE", e.getMessage());
        }

        return convTime;
    }

}
```

and i used it like this

```
 String time = jsonObject.getString("date_gmt");
 TimeAgo2 timeAgo2 = new TimeAgo2();
String MyFinalValue = timeAgo2.covertTimeToText(time);
```

Happy coding and thanks @Excelso_Widi you the man *wink*

Answer (score 21):

It's very simple. I'll tell you with my code.

```
package com.example;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TimeShow
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try 
        {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss");
            Date past = format.parse("2016.02.05 AD at 23:59:30");
            Date now = new Date();
            long seconds=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(now.getTime() - past.getTime());
            long minutes=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(now.getTime() - past.getTime());
            long hours=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(now.getTime() - past.getTime());
            long days=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(now.getTime() - past.getTime());
//
//          System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " milliseconds ago");
//          System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " minutes ago");
//          System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " hours ago");
//          System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(now.getTime() - past.getTime()) + " days ago");

            if(seconds<60)
            {
                System.out.println(seconds+" seconds ago");
            }
            else if(minutes<60)
            {
                System.out.println(minutes+" minutes ago");
            }
            else if(hours<24)
            {
                System.out.println(hours+" hours ago");
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println(days+" days ago");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception j){
            j.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Please help me parse : " 2016-01-24T16:00:00.000Z . Thanks you very much!

Comment: you need not parse. I'm using parse because i'm creating demo dateformat  for you. I think you already have a date format, just convert it to string & then create Date object for current date. After this just use my logic & it will give you perfect result what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 11):

In Android you can use *DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(long timeInMillis)*, referring to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html you can use one of the variations of that method for accuracy.

Comment: Looks like this only works for timestamps within a week

Answer (score 10):

Kotlin version

```
private const val SECOND_MILLIS = 1000
private const val MINUTE_MILLIS = 60 * SECOND_MILLIS
private const val HOUR_MILLIS = 60 * MINUTE_MILLIS
private const val DAY_MILLIS = 24 * HOUR_MILLIS

private fun currentDate(): Date {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    return calendar.time
}

fun getTimeAgo(date: Date): String {
    var time = date.time
    if (time < 1000000000000L) {
        time *= 1000
    }

    val now = currentDate().time
    if (time > now || time <= 0) {
        return "in the future"
    }

    val diff = now - time
    return when {
        diff < MINUTE_MILLIS -> "moments ago"
        diff < 2 * MINUTE_MILLIS -> "a minute ago"
        diff < 60 * MINUTE_MILLIS -> "${diff / MINUTE_MILLIS} minutes ago"
        diff < 2 * HOUR_MILLIS -> "an hour ago"
        diff < 24 * HOUR_MILLIS -> "${diff / HOUR_MILLIS} hours ago"
        diff < 48 * HOUR_MILLIS -> "yesterday"
        else -> "${diff / DAY_MILLIS} days ago"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**Easiest way**

For Kotlin (time in millisecond)

```kotlin
private const val SECOND = 1
private const val MINUTE = 60 * SECOND
private const val HOUR = 60 * MINUTE
private const val DAY = 24 * HOUR
private const val MONTH = 30 * DAY
private const val YEAR = 12 * MONTH

private fun currentDate(): Long {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    return calendar.timeInMillis
}

// Long: time in millisecond
fun Long.toTimeAgo(): String {
    val time = this
    val now = currentDate()

    // convert back to second
    val diff = (now - time) / 1000

    return when {
        diff < MINUTE -> "Just now"
        diff < 2 * MINUTE -> "a minute ago"
        diff < 60 * MINUTE -> "${diff / MINUTE} minutes ago"
        diff < 2 * HOUR -> "an hour ago"
        diff < 24 * HOUR -> "${diff / HOUR} hours ago"
        diff < 2 * DAY -> "yesterday"
        diff < 30 * DAY -> "${diff / DAY} days ago"
        diff < 2 * MONTH -> "a month ago"
        diff < 12 * MONTH -> "${diff / MONTH} months ago"
        diff < 2 * YEAR -> "a year ago"
        else -> "${diff / YEAR} years ago"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

For kotlin, you can use this extension function.

```
fun Date.getTimeAgo(): String {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.time = this

    val year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    val hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
    val minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

    val currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    val currentYear = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val currentMonth = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val currentDay = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    val currentHour = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
    val currentMinute = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

    return if (year < currentYear ) {
        val interval = currentYear - year
        if (interval == 1) "$interval year ago" else "$interval years ago"
    } else if (month < currentMonth) {
        val interval = currentMonth - month
        if (interval == 1) "$interval month ago" else "$interval months ago"
    } else  if (day < currentDay) {
        val interval = currentDay - day
        if (interval == 1) "$interval day ago" else "$interval days ago"
    } else if (hour < currentHour) {
        val interval = currentHour - hour
        if (interval == 1) "$interval hour ago" else "$interval hours ago"
    } else if (minute < currentMinute) {
        val interval = currentMinute - minute
        if (interval == 1) "$interval minute ago" else "$interval minutes ago"
    } else {
        "a moment ago"
    }
}

// To use it
val timeAgo = someDate.getTimeAgo()
```

Comment: Can you post a Java code instead of Kotlin?

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this.

Comment: This code doesn't work correctly. If ur date is Jan 29, and currentDate is Feb 1, it will show 1 month ago.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass milliseconds in getlongtoago method and you get return perfect formatted string

```
public static String getlongtoago(long createdAt) {
    DateFormat userDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
    DateFormat dateFormatNeeded = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS");
    Date date = null;
    date = new Date(createdAt);
    String crdate1 = dateFormatNeeded.format(date);

    // Date Calculation
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    crdate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(date);

    // get current date time with Calendar()
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String currenttime = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());

    Date CreatedAt = null;
    Date current = null;
    try {
        CreatedAt = dateFormat.parse(crdate1);
        current = dateFormat.parse(currenttime);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Get msec from each, and subtract.
    long diff = current.getTime() - CreatedAt.getTime();
    long diffSeconds = diff / 1000;
    long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
    long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
    long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    String time = null;
    if (diffDays > 0) {
        if (diffDays == 1) {
            time = diffDays + "day ago ";
        } else {
            time = diffDays + "days ago ";
        }
    } else {
        if (diffHours > 0) {
            if (diffHours == 1) {
                time = diffHours + "hr ago";
            } else {
                time = diffHours + "hrs ago";
            }
        } else {
            if (diffMinutes > 0) {
                if (diffMinutes == 1) {
                    time = diffMinutes + "min ago";
                } else {
                    time = diffMinutes + "mins ago";
                }
            } else {
                if (diffSeconds > 0) {
                    time = diffSeconds + "secs ago";
                }
            }

        }

    }
    return time;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class TimeUtility {

public String covertTimeToText(String dataDate) {

    String convTime = null;

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date pasTime = dateFormat.parse(dataDate);

        Date nowTime = new Date();

        long dateDiff = nowTime.getTime() - pasTime.getTime();

        long detik = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(dateDiff);
        long menit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(dateDiff);
        long jam   = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(dateDiff);
        long hari  = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(dateDiff);

        if (detik < 60) {
            convTime = detik+"detik lalu";
        } else if (menit < 60) {
            convTime = menit+"menit lalu";
        } else if (jam < 24) {
            convTime = jam+"jam lalu";
        } else if (hari >= 7) {
            if (hari > 30) {
                convTime = (hari / 30)+"bulan lalu";
            } else if (hari > 360) {
                convTime = (hari / 360)+"tahun lalu";
            } else {
                convTime = (hari / 7) + "minggu lalu";
            }
        } else if (hari < 7) {
            convTime = hari+"hari lalu";
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("ConvTimeE", e.getMessage());
    }

    return convTime;

  }

}
```

Comment: can you provide more clarity for this. can you check this if you need help https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: thanks for this fam, i translated and modified your code below hope you don't mind?

Answer (score 2):

You can select what type format you want both method are tested and working fine.

```
/*
* It's return date  before one week timestamp
*  like return
*  1 day ago
*  2 days ago
*  5 days ago
*  21 April 2019
*
* */
public static String getTimeAgoDate(long pastTimeStamp) {

    // for 2 min ago   use  DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS
    // for 2 sec ago   use  DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS
    // for 1 hours ago use  DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (now - pastTimeStamp < 1000) {
        pastTimeStamp = pastTimeStamp + 1000;
    }
    CharSequence ago =
            DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(pastTimeStamp, now, DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
    return ago.toString();
}


/*
 *
 * It's return date  before one week timestamp
 *
 *  like return
 *
 *  1 day ago
 *  2 days ago
 *  5 days ago
 *  2 weeks ago
 *  2 months ago
 *  2 years ago
 *
 *
 * */

public static String getTimeAgo(long mReferenceTime) {

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final long diff = now - mReferenceTime;
    if (diff < android.text.format.DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS) {
        return (diff <= 1000) ?
                "just now" :
                android.text.format.DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(mReferenceTime, now, DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS,
                        DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE).toString();
    } else if (diff <= 4 * android.text.format.DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS) {
        int week = (int)(diff / (android.text.format.DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS));
        return  week>1?week+" weeks ago":week+" week ago";
    } else if (diff < android.text.format.DateUtils.YEAR_IN_MILLIS) {
        int month = (int)(diff / (4 * android.text.format.DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS));
        return  month>1?month+" months ago":month+" month ago";
    } else {
        int year = (int) (diff/DateUtils.YEAR_IN_MILLIS);
        return year>1?year+" years ago":year+" year ago";
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please check the code below to do this perfectly in a modular and reusable way which will also return you the future time as like **5 minutes later** also. First, you need to create the `UnixToHuman` class in your project I mention below. Then you need to convert the server returned string into UNIX timestamp by

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
long time = sdf.parse("2016-01-24T16:00:00.000Z").getTime();
```

Then you need to just call the function `UnixToHuman.getTimeAgo(long time)` where `time` is your UNIX time which will return the desired string. The **UnixToHuman.java** is

```
public class UnixToHuman {
    private static final int SECOND_MILLIS = 1000;
    private static final int MINUTE_MILLIS = 60 * SECOND_MILLIS;
    private static final int HOUR_MILLIS = 60 * MINUTE_MILLIS;
    private static final int DAY_MILLIS = 24 * HOUR_MILLIS;
    private static final int WEEK_MILLIS = 7 * DAY_MILLIS ;

    public static String getTimeAgo(long time) {
        if (time < 1000000000000L) {
            // if timestamp given in seconds, convert to millis
            time *= 1000;
        }

        long now =System.currentTimeMillis();;


        long diff = now - time;
        if(diff>0) {


            if (diff < MINUTE_MILLIS) {
                return "just now";
            } else if (diff < 2 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
                return "a minute ago";
            } else if (diff < 50 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
                return diff / MINUTE_MILLIS + " minutes ago";
            } else if (diff < 90 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
                return "an hour ago";
            } else if (diff < 24 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
                return diff / HOUR_MILLIS + " hours ago";
            } else if (diff < 48 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
                return "yesterday";
            } else if (diff < 7 * DAY_MILLIS) {
                return diff / DAY_MILLIS + " days ago";
            } else if (diff < 2 * WEEK_MILLIS) {
                return "a week ago";
            } else if (diff < WEEK_MILLIS * 3) {
                return diff / WEEK_MILLIS + " weeks ago";
            } else {
                java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date((long) time);
                return date.toString();
            }

        }
        else {

            diff=time-now;
            if (diff < MINUTE_MILLIS) {
                return "this minute";
            } else if (diff < 2 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
                return "a minute later";
            } else if (diff < 50 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
                return diff / MINUTE_MILLIS + " minutes later";
            } else if (diff < 90 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
                return "an hour later";
            } else if (diff < 24 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
                return diff / HOUR_MILLIS + " hours later";
            } else if (diff < 48 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
                return "tomorrow";
            } else if (diff < 7 * DAY_MILLIS) {
                return diff / DAY_MILLIS + " days later";
            } else if (diff < 2 * WEEK_MILLIS) {
                return "a week later";
            } else if (diff < WEEK_MILLIS * 3) {
                return diff / WEEK_MILLIS + " weeks later";
            } else {
                java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date((long) time);
                return date.toString();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Modified Above Answer:**

```
public class TimeAgo {



   public String covertTimeToText(String dataDate) {

        String convertTime = null;
    String suffix = "ago";

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        Date pasTime = dateFormat.parse(dataDate);

        Date nowTime = new Date();

        long dateDiff = nowTime.getTime() - pasTime.getTime();

        long second = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(dateDiff);
        long minute = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(dateDiff);
        long hour = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(dateDiff);
        long day = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(dateDiff);

        if (second < 60) {
            if (second == 1) {
                convertTime = second + " second " + suffix;
            } else {
                convertTime = second + " seconds " + suffix;
            }
        } else if (minute < 60) {
            if (minute == 1) {
                convertTime = minute + " minute " + suffix;
            } else {
                convertTime = minute + " minutes " + suffix;
            }
        } else if (hour < 24) {
            if (hour == 1) {
                convertTime = hour + " hour " + suffix;
            } else {
                convertTime = hour + " hours " + suffix;
            }
        } else if (day >= 7) {
            if (day >= 365) {
                long tempYear = day / 365;
                if (tempYear == 1) {
                    convertTime = tempYear + " year " + suffix;
                } else {
                    convertTime = tempYear + " years " + suffix;
                }
            } else if (day >= 30) {
                long tempMonth = day / 30;
                if (tempMonth == 1) {
                    convertTime = (day / 30) + " month " + suffix;
                } else {
                    convertTime = (day / 30) + " months " + suffix;
                }
            } else {
                long tempWeek = day / 7;
                if (tempWeek == 1) {
                    convertTime = (day / 7) + " week " + suffix;
                } else {
                    convertTime = (day / 7) + " weeks " + suffix;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (day == 1) {
                convertTime = day + " day " + suffix;
            } else {
                convertTime = day + " days " + suffix;
            }
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("TimeAgo", e.getMessage() + "");
    }
    return convertTime;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:** You can use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html) to model [ISO_8601#Duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). With *Java-9* some more convenience methods were introduced.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String strDateTime = "2016-01-24T16:00:00.000Z";
        Instant then = Instant.parse(strDateTime);
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        Duration duration = Duration.between(then, now);
        System.out.println(duration);

        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        String formatted = String.format("%d days %02d hours %02d minutes %02d seconds %02d milliseconds ago",
                duration.toDays(), duration.toHours() % 24, duration.toMinutes() % 60, duration.toSeconds() % 60,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(duration.toNanos() % 1000_000_000, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS));
        System.out.println(formatted);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        formatted = String.format("%d days %02d hours %02d minutes %02d seconds %02d milliseconds ago",
                duration.toDaysPart(), duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(), duration.toSecondsPart(),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(duration.toNanosPart(), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS));
        System.out.println(formatted);
        // ####################################Java-9####################################
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PT50117H11M53.914442S
2088 days 05 hours 11 minutes 53 seconds 914 milliseconds ago
2088 days 05 hours 11 minutes 53 seconds 914 milliseconds ago
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/I8Hfod)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

this work for me

```
fun dateFormat(date: String): String{
    val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.getDefault())
    val dateTime = simpleDateFormat.parse(date)
    val now = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis
    val result = android.text.format.DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(dateTime.time, now, android.text.format.DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS)
    return result.toString()


}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to convert is `ISO 8601` compliant format. The easiest way to convert this is by using [Joda-Time library](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android) for Android.

Once you add that to your project, you can use this code to extract the exact date!

```
    DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMMM yyyy").withZone(timeZone);
    DateTime dateTime2 = new DateTime( isoDateToBeConverted, timeZone );
    String output = formatter.print( dateTime2 );
    Log.w("TIME IF WORKS::",""+output);
```

Also, see [this](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html) to format the date in your preferred choice
Hope it helps!

Comment: Mark it as an answer if it helps!

Comment: What is isoDateToBeConverted ? @shaheen

Comment: `2016-01-24T16:00:00.000Z` date of something like this

Comment: This answer is completely missing the "time ago" part of the question, something Joda-Time is not well designed for.

Comment: Wasn't thinking of `spoonfeeding` the hardest part was to change that to a proper date format from the ISO format, switching to time ago would only take some extra few lines of code!

Comment: Well, if you only want English then printing time ago might be considered as simple although it is still more effort than using a dedicated time-ago-capable-library, but if you think of more languages then such a  task becomes horror when writing the own manual workaround.

Answer (score 1):

As I went through all the answers, there are a bunch of ways to get the solution for this query anyhow the below answer does not require any third-party modules or any native util classes, you can get the result from native Java using the below technique also it's a memory-optimized answer, it won't consume your memory much.

Usage:

```
HumanDateUtils.durationFromNow(startDate)
```

You can customize this method as your wish by adding `ago or seen`.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class HumanDateUtils {

    public static String durationFromNow(Date startDate) {

        long different = System.currentTimeMillis() - startDate.getTime();

        long secondsInMilli = 1000;
        long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
        long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
        long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;

        long elapsedDays = different / daysInMilli;
        different = different % daysInMilli;

        long elapsedHours = different / hoursInMilli;
        different = different % hoursInMilli;

        long elapsedMinutes = different / minutesInMilli;
        different = different % minutesInMilli;

        long elapsedSeconds = different / secondsInMilli;

        String output = "";
        if (elapsedDays > 0) output += elapsedDays + "days ";
        if (elapsedDays > 0 || elapsedHours > 0) output += elapsedHours + " hours ";
        if (elapsedHours > 0 || elapsedMinutes > 0) output += elapsedMinutes + " minutes ";
        if (elapsedMinutes > 0 || elapsedSeconds > 0) output += elapsedSeconds + " seconds";

        return output;
    }
}
```

Output: 
**12 days 12 hours 25 minutes 4 seconds**

Reference: [Human Readable Date - Java](https://gist.github.com/aslamanver/063d129dd37a2828fc51576f7a4740ab)

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

I was facing same issue(**Unhandled execption java.text.ParseExecption**) when trying to convert timestamp into time ago format ,after doing R&D finally i got the solutions...now this error have been solved

- Add this(**compile 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.1.Final'**) dependency in your bulid.gradle(Module:app) and sync your project
- After adding this dependency paste this method and call it where you want like (Log.e("TAG", "ConvertTimeStampintoAgo: "+ConvertTimeStampintoAgo(1320917972));)

  ```
  public static String ConvertTimeStampintoAgo(Long timeStamp)
  {
  try
  {
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
      cal.setTimeInMillis(timeStamp);
      String date = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", cal).toString();
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
      Date dateObj = sdf.parse(date);
      PrettyTime p = new PrettyTime();
      return p.format(dateObj);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return "";
  }
  ```

  **Note** it will show
- moment ago(current time)
- minute ago
- day ago

Answer (score 0):

too late but try this,

```
 public static String parseDate(String givenDateString) {
    if (givenDateString.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        return "";
    }

    long timeInMilliseconds=0;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    try {

        Date mDate = sdf.parse(givenDateString);
        timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
        System.out.println("Date in milli :: " + timeInMilliseconds);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    String result = "now";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");

    String todayDate = formatter.format(new Date());
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    long dayagolong =  timeInMilliseconds;
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(dayagolong);
    String agoformater = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());

    Date CurrentDate = null;
    Date CreateDate = null;

    try {
        CurrentDate = formatter.parse(todayDate);
        CreateDate = formatter.parse(agoformater);

        long different = Math.abs(CurrentDate.getTime() - CreateDate.getTime());

        long secondsInMilli = 1000;
        long minutesInMilli = secondsInMilli * 60;
        long hoursInMilli = minutesInMilli * 60;
        long daysInMilli = hoursInMilli * 24;

        long elapsedDays = different / daysInMilli;
        different = different % daysInMilli;

        long elapsedHours = different / hoursInMilli;
        different = different % hoursInMilli;

        long elapsedMinutes = different / minutesInMilli;
        different = different % minutesInMilli;

        long elapsedSeconds = different / secondsInMilli;

        different = different % secondsInMilli;
        if (elapsedDays == 0) {
            if (elapsedHours == 0) {
                if (elapsedMinutes == 0) {
                    if (elapsedSeconds < 0) {
                        return "0" + " s";
                    } else {
                        if (elapsedDays > 0 && elapsedSeconds < 59) {
                            return "now";
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    return String.valueOf(elapsedMinutes) + "mins ago";
                }
            } else {
                return String.valueOf(elapsedHours) + "hr ago";
            }

        } else {
            if (elapsedDays <= 29) {
                return String.valueOf(elapsedDays) + "d ago";

            }
            else if (elapsedDays > 29 && elapsedDays <= 58) {
                return "1Mth ago";
            }
            if (elapsedDays > 58 && elapsedDays <= 87) {
                return "2Mth ago";
            }
            if (elapsedDays > 87 && elapsedDays <= 116) {
                return "3Mth ago";
            }
            if (elapsedDays > 116 && elapsedDays <= 145) {
                return "4Mth ago";
            }
            if (elapsedDays > 145 && elapsedDays <= 174) {
                return "5Mth ago";
            }
            if (elapsedDays > 174 && elapsedDays <= 203) {
                return "6Mth ago";
            }
            if (elapsedDays > 203 && elapsedDays <= 232) {
                return "7Mth ago";
            }
            if (elapsedDays > 232 && elapsedDays <= 261) {
                return "8Mth ago";
            }
            if (elapsedDays > 261 && elapsedDays <= 290) {
                return "9Mth ago";
            }
            if (elapsedDays > 290 && elapsedDays <= 319) {
                return "10Mth ago";
            }
            if (elapsedDays > 319 && elapsedDays <= 348) {
                return "11Mth ago";
            }
            if (elapsedDays > 348 && elapsedDays <= 360) {
                return "12Mth ago";
            }

            if (elapsedDays > 360 && elapsedDays <= 720) {
                return "1 year ago";
            }
        }

    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a Kotlin extension function (Replace App.context with your own context):

```
fun Long.msToTimeAgo(): String {
    val seconds = (System.currentTimeMillis() - this) / 1000f

    return when (true) {
        seconds < 60 -> App.context.resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.seconds_ago, seconds.toInt(), seconds.toInt())
        seconds < 3600 -> {
            val minutes = seconds / 60f
            App.context.resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.minutes_ago, minutes.toInt(), minutes.toInt())
        }
        seconds < 86400 -> {
            val hours = seconds / 3600f
            App.context.resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.hours_ago, hours.toInt(), hours.toInt())
        }
        seconds < 604800 -> {
            val days = seconds / 86400f
            App.context.resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.days_ago, days.toInt(), days.toInt())
        }
        seconds < 2_628_000 -> {
            val weeks = seconds / 604800f
            App.context.resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.weeks_ago, weeks.toInt(), weeks.toInt())
        }
        seconds < 31_536_000 -> {
            val months = seconds / 2_628_000f
            App.context.resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.months_ago, months.toInt(), months.toInt())
        }
        else -> {
            val years = seconds / 31_536_000f
            App.context.resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.years_ago, years.toInt(), years.toInt())
        }
    }
}
```

Add the following to your string resources:

```
<plurals name="seconds_ago">
    <item quantity="one">%d second ago</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d seconds ago</item>
</plurals>

<plurals name="minutes_ago">
    <item quantity="one">%d minute ago</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d minutes ago</item>
</plurals>

<plurals name="hours_ago">
    <item quantity="one">%d hour ago</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d hours ago</item>
</plurals>

<plurals name="days_ago">
    <item quantity="one">%d day ago</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d days ago</item>
</plurals>

<plurals name="weeks_ago">
    <item quantity="one">%d week ago</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d weeks ago</item>
</plurals>

<plurals name="months_ago">
    <item quantity="one">%d month ago</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d months ago</item>
</plurals>

<plurals name="years_ago">
    <item quantity="one">%d year ago</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d years ago</item>
</plurals>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, I am too late, but maybe it help you.
If you want to find the time ago format with the current date(long) and your old date (long), Please check the below code.

```
public static CharSequence covertTimeToText(long dataDate) {

        String convTime = null;

        String prefix = "";
        String suffix = "Ago";
        int i = 13 -String.valueOf(dataDate).length();
        long l = 0L;
        switch (i){
            case 1:
                l = dataDate * 10;
                break;
            case 2:
                l = dataDate * 100;
                break;
            case 3:
                l = dataDate * 1000;
                break;
            case 4:
                l = dataDate * 10000;
                break;
            case 5:
                l = dataDate * 100000;
                break;
            case 6:
                l = dataDate * 1000000;
                break;

        }

        try {
            Date nowTime = new Date();
            long dateDiff = nowTime.getTime() - l;

            long second = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(dateDiff);
            long minute = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(dateDiff);
            long hour   = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(dateDiff);
            long day  = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(dateDiff);

            if (second < 60) {
                convTime = second + " Seconds " + suffix;
            } else if (minute < 60) {
                convTime = minute + " Minutes "+suffix;
            } else if (hour < 24) {
                convTime = hour + " Hours "+suffix;
            } else if (day >= 7) {
                if (day > 360) {
                    convTime = (day / 360) + " Years " + suffix;
                } else if (day > 30) {
                    convTime = (day / 30) + " Months " + suffix;
                } else {
                    convTime = (day / 7) + " Week " + suffix;
                }
            } else if (day < 7) {
                convTime = day+" Days "+suffix;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convTime;
    }
```