# How to show date and time in time ago using calendar in android

Tags: android

How to show date and time in time ago using calendar in android . Like 2 days ago , 1 month ago . I have tried without using calendar . But if we use calendar we can avoid 28 and 30 days in a month problem . How to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert time to " time ago " in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858608/how-to-convert-time-to-time-ago-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

Follow these 3 simple steps:
1. Save the time/date of the activity occurred (for which you want to show $ months or $ days ago)
2. Calculate the current time/date.
3. Take a difference between in current time and last saved time then use the same into showing your desired result.

```
String dateStart = "01/14/2017 10:20:18";
        String dateStop = "01/15/2018 11:41:38";

        //HH converts hour in 24 hours format (0-23), day calculation
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        Date d1 = null;
        Date d2 = null;

        try {
            d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
            d2 = format.parse(dateStop);

            //in milliseconds
            long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

            long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
            long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
            long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
            long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

            System.out.print(diffDays + " days, ");
            System.out.print(diffHours + " hours, ");
            System.out.print(diffMinutes + " minutes, ");
            System.out.print(diffSeconds + " seconds.");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code may be you found it useful

```
public static String getAgoTime(String p_date, SimpleDateFormat p_dateFormat) throws Throwable {
        String message_Time = "";
        // SimpleDateFormat m_dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat(p_dateFormat);
        Date m_currentdate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        String m_today = p_dateFormat.format(m_currentdate);
        Date showTime = p_dateFormat.parse(p_date);
        Date server_date = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.SHOW_DATE_FORMAT).parse(p_date);
        Date today_date = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.SHOW_DATE_FORMAT).parse(m_today);

        long m_diff = today_date.getTime() - server_date.getTime();

        int hours = (int) (m_diff / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        int mins = (int) ((m_diff / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
        if (server_date.compareTo(today_date) == 0) {
/*
            if (hours == 0) {
                message_Time = String.valueOf(mins + " mins ago");
            } else if (hours > 1 && hours < 23) {
                message_Time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").format(m_date1);
            }
*/
            message_Time = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.SHOW_TIME_FORMAT).format(showTime);

        } else if (server_date.compareTo(today_date) < 0) {
            message_Time = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.SHOW_INDEX_DATE).format(server_date);
        }
        return message_Time;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

```
private long getTimesAgo(String dateValue){
        try{
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(Constants.DateFormat.GMT));

        long time = sdf.parse(dateValue).getTime();
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        CharSequence ago = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(time, now, DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
        return ago.toString();

        }catch (Exception e){
            return 0;
        }
    }
```