# Format remaining time untill date

Tags: android, date-format

I have a date in the future and have to format the remaining time until this day like so.

4 days

1 month, 4 days

1 year, 1 month

I have looked at the DateUtils documentation but haven't seen this exact format.

I'm also fine using an external library like threetenabp.

Is there a library that can handle both the time calculation and the localization of the strings?

Comment: It’s not my home field, but I think that Joda-Time can do something like that. Joda-Time is on its way to retirement, though, so I might still consider something homegrown on top of [the ThreeTenABP library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) that you mentioned.

Comment: My [answer to this elder SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35860996/2491410) should link you into the right direction - with some adjustments for date-only remaining time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this blog a while ago, it shows how to do the opposite of what you are asking :-) https://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/creating-comments-with-timestamps-like-youtube/ i.e. given a time, say how long ago that was. 
Android also offers this solution for times in the past: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeDateTimeString(android.content.Context,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20int). 
So you need the opposite of these!

It should not be too hard to inverse. Instead of using the time now and negating the difference of a time in the past. You use the time now and add the time in the future.

So the inverse of: https://github.com/blundell/YouTubeTimeStamps/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/blundell/tut/TimeStampFormatter.kt

The main difference being you want a difference between now and a date in the future, like so:

```
private fun getMillisFromNow(futureTime: Date): Long {
    val futureTimeMillis = futureTime.time
    val nowMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    return futureTimeMillis - nowMillis
}
```

And then format it. Something like this:

```
 fun format(timestamp: Date): String {
    val millisFromNow = getMillisFromNow(timestamp)

    val minutesFromNow = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisFromNow)
    if (minutesFromNow < 1) {
        return "about now"
    }
    val hoursFromNow = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisFromNow)
    if (hoursFromNow < 1) {
        return formatMinutes(minutesFromNow)
    }
    val daysFromNow = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisFromNow)
    if (daysFromNow < 1) {
        return formatHours(hoursFromNow)
    }
    val weeksFromNow = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisFromNow) / 7
    if (weeksFromNow < 1) {
        return formatDays(daysFromNow)
    }
    val monthsFromNow = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisFromNow) / 30
    if (monthsFromNow < 1) {
        return formatWeeks(weeksFromNow)
    }
    val yearsFromNow = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(millisFromNow) / 365
    return if (yearsFromNow < 1) {
        formatMonths(monthsFromNow)
    } else formatYears(yearsFromNow)
}

 private fun getMillisFromNow(futureTime: Date): Long {
    val futureTimeMillis = futureTime.time
    val nowMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    return futureTimeMillis - nowMillis
}

private fun formatMinutes(minutes: Long): String {
    return format(minutes, " minute to go", " minutes to go")
}

private fun formatHours(hours: Long): String {
    return format(hours, " hour to go", " hours to go")
}

private fun formatDays(days: Long): String {
    return format(days, " day to go", " days to go")
}

private fun formatWeeks(weeks: Long): String {
    return format(weeks, " week to go", " weeks to go")
}

private fun formatMonths(months: Long): String {
    return format(months, " month to go", " months to go")
}

private fun formatYears(years: Long): String {
    return format(years, " year to go", " years to go")
}

private fun format(hand: Long, singular: String, plural: String): String {
    return if (hand == 1L) {
        hand.toString() + singular
    } else {
        hand.toString() + plural
    }
}
```

Just sanity checked it with this test:

```
@Test
fun test() {
    val twoDaysInMillisInstant = Instant.now().plusMillis(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(50))
    val result = format(Date.from(twoDaysInMillisInstant))

    assertEquals("2 days to go", result)
}
```

For the localization, you can convert this to using `Strings.xml`.

Comment: I have gone with a similar approach to this one so I'm marking it as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

using threeten's **LocalDate** you can get the remaining years, months and day from one date to another. Having that values you can 0-check them and show only ones that are > 0.
Simple example:

```
    val futureDate = LocalDate.of(2020,2,20)
    val todayDate = LocalDate.now()
    val remainingYears = futureDate.year - todayDate.year //output 0
    val remainingMonth = futureDate.monthValue - todayDate.monthValue //output 0
    val remainingDays = futureDate.dayOfMonth - todayDate.dayOfMonth // output 16
```

I hope that is what you wanted, cheers!

Comment: Using `LocalDate` is a fine start. You’re not there yet. When I put in `LocalDate.of(2021, 1, 20)` in you code, I 1 for years, -1 for months and 16 for days. I had rather expected 11 months 16 days.