# Date Time Ago Converter

Tags: android, timestamp

I have a timestamp from the response in a string and I am trying to convert it to display time ago.

However, my converter is having an issue that it is late than the current time for 1 hour, 1 day, etc...

For example, this given timestamp `1610959169` is showing `18 hours ago` while I am posting the question here. And actually, I have to convert it online it was given the result in `19 hours ago`.

Please check on below snip of code for the convert class.

```
object DateTimeConvertUtil {
private val SECOND_MILLIS = 1000
private val MINUTE_MILLIS = 60 * SECOND_MILLIS
private val HOUR_MILLIS = 60 * MINUTE_MILLIS
private val DAY_MILLIS = 24 * HOUR_MILLIS
private val WEEK_MILLIS = 7 * DAY_MILLIS

fun getCreatedTime(givenTime: Long, isShowingWeek: Boolean? = false): String? {
    var time = givenTime
    if (time < 1000000000000L) {
        time *= 1000
    }
    val now = System.currentTimeMillis()
    if (time > now || time <= 0) {
        return null
    }
    val diff = now - time
    when {
        diff < MINUTE_MILLIS -> return "Just now"
        diff < 2 * MINUTE_MILLIS -> return "a minute ago"
        diff < 50 * MINUTE_MILLIS -> return "${diff / MINUTE_MILLIS} minutes ago"
        diff < 90 * MINUTE_MILLIS -> return "an hour ago"
        diff < 24 * HOUR_MILLIS -> return "${diff / HOUR_MILLIS} hours ago"
        diff < 48 * HOUR_MILLIS -> return "Yesterday"
        diff < 7 * DAY_MILLIS -> return "${diff / DAY_MILLIS} days ago"
        else -> {
            return if (isShowingWeek!!) {
                when {
                    diff / WEEK_MILLIS <= 1 -> "${diff / WEEK_MILLIS} week ago"
                    diff / WEEK_MILLIS <= 52 -> "${diff / WEEK_MILLIS} weeks ago"
                    diff / WEEK_MILLIS <= 104 -> "a year ago"
                    else -> "2 years ago"
                }
            } else {
                showDate(time.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me with this issue. Thank you.

Comment: `val date = Date(timeStamp * 1000) val ago = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(date.time,
        System.currentTimeMillis(),DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS,DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL).toString()` try  this

Comment: @Raghunandan -- your suggestion is quite pretty good. But we need to adjust the text output if we want to display actually wording. Anyway, thank you for your comment. Have a good day.

Comment: oh right the wording are differnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this class for Time ago

```
public class TimeAgo {
    public final static String monthAgo = " Month z";
    public final static String monthsAgo = " Months ago";

    public final static String weekAgo = " Week ago";
    public final static String weeksAgo = " Weeks ago";

    public final static String daysAgo = " Days ago";
    public final static String dayAgo = " Day ago";

    public final static String hourAgo = " Hour ago";
    public final static String hoursAgo = " Hours ago";

    public final static String minAgo = " Min ago";
    public final static String minsAgo = " Mins ago";

    public final static String secsAgo = " Secs ago";
    public final static String secAgo = "Just Now";
    static int second = 1000; // milliseconds
    static int minute = 60;
    static int hour = minute * 60;
    static int day = hour * 24;
    static int week = day * 7;
    static int month = day * 30;
    static int year = month * 12;

    public static String DateDifference(long fromDate) {
        long diff = 0;
        long ms2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // get difference in milli seconds
        diff = ms2 - fromDate;

        int diffInSec = Math.abs((int) (diff / (second)));
        String difference = "";
        if (diffInSec < minute) {
            if (diffInSec <= 1) {

                difference = secAgo;

            } else {
                difference = diffInSec + secsAgo;
            }
        } else if ((diffInSec / hour) < 1) {
            if ((diffInSec / minute) <= 1) {
                difference = (diffInSec / minute) + minAgo;
            } else {
                difference = (diffInSec / minute) + minsAgo;
            }
        } else if ((diffInSec / day) < 1) {
            if ((diffInSec / hour) <= 1) {
                difference = (diffInSec / hour) + hourAgo;
            } else {
                difference = (diffInSec / hour) + hoursAgo;
            }

        } else if ((diffInSec / week) < 1) {
            if ((diffInSec / day) <= 1) {
                difference = (diffInSec / day) + dayAgo;
            } else {
                difference = (diffInSec / day) + daysAgo;
            }
        } else if ((diffInSec / month) < 1) {
            if ((diffInSec / week) <= 1) {
                difference = (diffInSec / week) + weekAgo;
            } else {
                difference = (diffInSec / week) + weeksAgo;
            }

        } else if ((diffInSec / year) < 1) {
            if ((diffInSec / month) <= 1) {
                difference = (diffInSec / month) + monthAgo;
            } else {
                difference = (diffInSec / month) + monthsAgo;
            }
        } else {
            // return date
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTimeInMillis(fromDate);

            SimpleDateFormat format_before = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            difference = format_before.format(c.getTime());
        }
        Log.e("time difference is: ", "" + difference);
        return difference;
    }
}
```

and use this like this

```
TimeAgo.DateDifference(time);
```

Comment: It is a superb answer. Moreover, if you can addon to show the year it might be more perfect than this class can show all kind of timing. Thank you.

Comment: Yup I will definetely add

Comment: Still waiting to see your modified code to show the year.

Answer (score 0):

try changing these :

```
diff < MINUTE_MILLIS -> return "Just now"
diff < 2 * MINUTE_MILLIS -> return "a minute ago"
diff < 50 * MINUTE_MILLIS -> return "${diff / MINUTE_MILLIS} minutes ago"
diff < 90 * MINUTE_MILLIS -> return "an hour ago"
diff < 24 * HOUR_MILLIS -> return "${diff / HOUR_MILLIS} hours ago"
```

with

```
diff < MINUTE_MILLIS -> return "Just now"
diff < 2 * MINUTE_MILLIS -> return "a minute ago"
diff < 60 * MINUTE_MILLIS -> return "${diff / MINUTE_MILLIS} minutes ago"
diff < 24 * HOUR_MILLIS -> return "${diff / HOUR_MILLIS} hours ago"
```

you need to change 50 to 60 and remove the check for < 90 and it will work fine also you can refer here:

[How to convert time to " time ago " in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858608/how-to-convert-time-to-time-ago-in-android)