# Get relative date time in string format

Tags: java, datetime, kotlin

How to get relative Time of long time, e.g., "12 hours ago", like the highlighted text in this picture

[image]

```
val relative = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(1616782398.0.toLong())
Log.d("Debug Elapsed", relative.toString())
```

I try use DateUtils for this, but dont work because the result was Jan 19, 1970

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? I don’t believe that method can return such a string.

Comment: Please don't post text as images.  They're unreadable for screen-reader users and unpleasant to read for everyone else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert time to " time ago " in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858608/how-to-convert-time-to-time-ago-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

### [`Instant#ofEpochSecond`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-)

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1616782398L);
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-03-26T18:13:18Z
```

You can convert `Instant` it to other types e.g.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1616782398L);

        // Replace ZoneId as applicable e.g. ZoneId.of("Europe/London")
        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        // Print ZonedDateTime#toString
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // Print custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE dd, MMMM uuuu hh:mm:ss a z", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(dtf.format(zdt));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-03-26T18:13:18Z[Europe/London]
Fri 26, March 2021 06:13:18 PM GMT
```

If you are looking for a duration between two `Instant`s, you can find it using [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html). With *Java-9* some more convenient methods were introduced.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Instant derived from the given epoch seconds
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1616782398L);

        // The current instant
        Instant now = Instant.now();

        // Duration between the two instants
        Duration duration = Duration.between(instant, now);

        // Print Duration#toString
        System.out.println(duration);

        // Custom format
        // ####################################Java-8####################################
        String formattedElapsedTime = String.format(
                "%d Day %02d Hour %02d Minute %02d Second %d Millisecond %d Nanosecond", duration.toDays(),
                duration.toHours() % 24, duration.toMinutes() % 60, duration.toSeconds() % 60,
                duration.toMillis() % 1000, duration.toNanos() % 1000000000L);
        System.out.println(formattedElapsedTime);
        // ##############################################################################

        // ####################################Java-9####################################
        formattedElapsedTime = String.format("%d Day %02d Hour %02d Minute %02d Second %d Millisecond %d Nanosecond",
                duration.toDaysPart(), duration.toHoursPart(), duration.toMinutesPart(), duration.toSecondsPart(),
                duration.toMillisPart(), duration.toNanosPart());
        System.out.println(formattedElapsedTime);
        // ##############################################################################
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
PT2H44M15.040731S
0 Day 02 Hour 44 Minute 15 Second 40 Millisecond 40731000 Nanosecond
0 Day 02 Hour 44 Minute 15 Second 40 Millisecond 40731000 Nanosecond
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `DateUtil` is, but you can simply use `java.time.Instant` and `Duration` for this:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Instant now = Instant.now();
      Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1616782398);
      Duration d = Duration.between(now, instant);
      System.out.println(d);
   }
}
```

Then you can use the `get` methods on `Duration` to retrieve your desired values and format them as you like.

As an alternative you can use `ChronoUnit` like this to get similar results:

```
ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(now, instant)
```